# How can I conditionally run YAML tasks based on path filters?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a number of solutions, each of which have a mixture of applications and libraries.  Generally speaking, the applications get built and deployed, and the libraries get published as NuGet packages to our internal packages feed.  I'll call these "apps" and "nugets."

In my Classic Pipelines, I would have one build for the apps, and one for the nugets.  With path filters, I would indicate folders that contain the nuget material, and only trigger the nuget build if those folders had changes.  Likewise, the app build would have path filters to detect if any app code had changed.  As a result, depending on what was changed in a branch, the app build might run, the nuget build might run, or both might run.

Now I'm trying to convert these to YAML.  It seems we can only have one pipeline set up for CI, so I've combined the stages/jobs/steps for nugets and apps into this single pipeline.  However, I can't seem to figure out a good way to only trigger the nuget tasks if the nuget path filters are satisfied and only the app tasks if the app path filters are satisfied.

I am hoping someone knows a way to do something similar to one of the following (or anything else that would solve the issue):

- Have two different CI pipelines with their own sets of triggers and branch/path filters such that one or both might run on a given branch change
- Set some variables based on which paths have changes so that I could later trigger the appropriate tasks using conditions
- Make a pipeline always trigger, but only do tasks if a path filter is satisfied (so that the nuget build could always run, but not necessarily do anything, and then the app build could be triggered by the nuget build completing, and itself only do stuff if path filters are satisfied.

Comment: *It seems we can only have one pipeline set up for CI* What gives you that impression? That is not accurate.

Comment: @DanielMann What I mean is it appears you can only choose one YAML file as the file that will kickoff when changes are pushed. Other reading on SO and elsewhere seemed to confirm this for me, but if I’m wrong, I’d love to know how to do it!

Comment: You can have multiple YAML files, multiple pipeline definitions, and multiple triggers. Common steps or jobs can be extracted as templates.

Comment: @DanielMann I think we might be on different pages. Yes, I have lots of templates involved here. What I’m essentially looking for is two azure-pipelines.yml files to be equally recognized. If path /app has changes, I want one of those to run. If path /nuget has changes, I want the other to run. If both have changes, I want both to run, sequentially or at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what the problem is. Make two separate pipeline YAML files: `apps.yml` and `packages.yml`. Make two pipelines, one pointing to `apps.yml` and the other to `packages.yml`. Define appropriate triggers. Both will be evaluated independently.

Comment: @DanielMann - I think I figured it out.  I already had two pipelines, but the only one that would run is the one selected in the Settings on the web UI.  I didn't realize I could use the UI to create another Pipeline and assign the other YAML file to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems we can only have one pipeline set up for CI

My issue was that this was an erroneous conclusion.  It appeared to me that, out of the box, a Pipeline is created for a repo with a YAML file in it, and that you can change which file the Pipeline uses, but you can't add a list of files for it to use.  I did not realize I could create an additional Pipeline in the UI, and then associate it to a different YAML file in the repo.

Basically, my inexperience with this topic is showing.  To future people who might find this, note that you can create as many Pipelines in the UI as you want, and associate each one to a different YAML file.